# Testing UWP app in development that uses GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync to check for store updates

Tags: uwp, windows-10-universal, windows-store

I'm adding code to my UWP app that will detect if mandatory updates are available and automatically download and install them. This app is being deployed by Microsoft Store for Business as an LOB app once it is ready for production use. During development I have not been able to run the app on my local machine from Visual Studio when I include code that checks for updates.

For instance when I execute this line of code:

```
IReadOnlyList<StorePackageUpdate> updates = await context.GetAppAndOptionalStorePackageUpdatesAsync();
```

The debugger just goes out to lunch. The CPU activity from the app drops to 0% and the memory usage goes flat.

I was hoping that I could implement the check for updates in the app and still be able to develop it locally, but I'm really missing something.

Appreciate any and all suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The official doc has implement an article about how we can testing the in app purchase function by associate your app with the dashboard. You can check it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/monetize/in-app-purchases-and-trials#test-your-in-app-purchase-or-trial-implementation). The storecontext object need a license to get it works on your current computer. What about give these steps a test? Is it what you want?

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I was able to follow the instructions in the link to make sure I was doing the right thing. It turns out my actual problem was poorly handled async code that I missed. I'm now able to get the code to run and am in the process of debugging it. Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Steve, is this still working for your LOB app? I have been struggling with this. https://github.com/microsoft/WinDev/issues/22

Comment: @CarloMendoza, we no longer use Windows Store to deploy the application. This code has been removed from our UWP app. We're now using a hosted AppInstaller with configured auto-update settings which has been working quite well. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/app-installer-root

Comment: @CarloMendoza Have you had any luck with https://github.com/microsoft/WinDev/issues/22 ? I am in same boat. Any help would be appreciated. No other way to reach you.

Comment: @john-g No. Windows devs didn't see this as important enough. I got nowhere with my contacts and gave up late last year. Unfortunately, it's also compounded by the fact that Store for Business is going away. I'm forced to distribute LOB apps some other way. No surprise, the suggested paths are also half-baked (winget, MSIX).